# How to extract URL parameters from a URL with Ruby or Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, uri, url-parameters

I have some URLs, like

```
http://www.example.com/something?param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3
```

and I would like to extract the parameters from these URLs and get them in a Hash. Obviously, I could use regular expressions, but I was just wondering if there was easier ways to do that with Ruby or Rails. I haven't found anything in the Ruby module `URI` but perhaps I missed something.

In fact, I need a method that would do that:

```
extract_parameters_from_url("http://www.example.com/something?param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3")
#=> {:param1 => 'value1', :param2 => 'value2', :param3 => 'value3'}
```

Would you have some advices?

Comment: `Hash[*string.split('&').collect{|i|i.split('=')}.flatten]`

This would work too, but it's probably the worst option for this case. But still you might find this snippet interesting. (Posting as comment since I don't consider this an answer :-))

Answer (score 189, accepted):

I think you want to turn any given URL string into a HASH?

You can try http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/classes/CGI.html#M000075

```
require 'cgi'

CGI::parse('param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3')
```

returns

```
{"param1"=>["value1"], "param2"=>["value2"], "param3"=>["value3"]}
```

Comment: OK, that was the one I missed! It's perfect when used with URI.parse :
CGI.parse(URI.parse("http://www.example.com/something?param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3").query) returns the desired Hash. Thanks for your help.

Comment: For clarity, @Flackou wants this:  `CGI.parse(URI.parse(url).query)`

Comment: I haven't tested this, but the first key listed, containing the full url, seems really wrong.

Comment: I actually had to use this:
    `CGI::parse(URI::parse(url).query)`

Comment: This solution won't work properly with arrays, like `a[]=1&a[]=2` will be parsed as `{"a[]"=>["1", "2"]}` whereas [Arthur's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3218018/895789) will parse `{"a"=>["1", "2"]}`

Answer (score 180):

I found myself needing the same thing for a recent project.
Building on Levi's solution, here's a cleaner and faster method:

```
Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query 'param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3'
# => {"param1"=>"value1", "param2"=>"value2", "param3"=>"value3"}
```

Comment: Much more lightweight than mocking a Rack request

Comment: Good find. If you have simple params (non-nested) and are performance sensitive, Rack::Utils.parse_query might be of interest. The code is worth reading: https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/utils.rb

Comment: This works well but does not work for checkboxes with the same name: `param1=value1&param1=value2`. The second value trumps the first.

Comment: For anyone looking for the inverse, it's `Rack::Utils.build_nested_query(params)` (or `Rack::Utils.build_query(params)` if parsed with `Rack::Utils.parse_query`).

Comment: This method crashes sometimes because of encoding issues. I found the `CGI:parse` method to be more stable (see answer above)

Answer (score 113):

Just Improved with Levi answer above -

```
Rack::Utils.parse_query URI("http://example.com?par=hello&par2=bye").query
```

For a string like above url, it will return

```
{ "par" => "hello", "par2" => "bye" }
```

Comment: great answer. simple, processes the full URL like the op asks, and the result values are strings instead of arrays, like in the other answers. thanks.

Comment: As I commented above, for anyone looking for the inverse, it's `Rack::Utils.build_query(params)`.

Comment: Beware - not quite the inverse, at least not in Ruby 1.8.7 / Rails 2.3.  A query string of foo[]=1&foo[]=2 is correctly parsed as { "foo" =>["1","2"] }, but build_query turns that into "foo=1&foo=2", which when parsed again yields { "foo"=>"2"}.

Comment: Took me a minute to realize that due to lack of wrapping params, this answer isn't readily extended. `Rack::Utils.parse_query(URI("http://example.com?par=hello&par2=bye").query)` yields a hash that can be further modified.

Answer (score 55):

For a pure Ruby solution combine `URI.parse` with `CGI.parse` (this can be used even if Rails/Rack etc. are not required):

```
CGI.parse(URI.parse(url).query) 
# =>  {"name1" => ["value1"], "name2" => ["value1", "value2", ...] }
```

Comment: This is elegant.

Answer (score 44):

There more than one ways, to solve your problem. Others has shown you the some tricks. I know another trick. Here is my try :-

```
require 'uri'
url = "http://www.example.com/something?param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3"
uri = URI(url)
# => #<URI::HTTP:0x89e4898 URL:http://www.example.com/something?param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3>
URI::decode_www_form(uri.query).to_h # if you are in 2.1 or later version of Ruby
# => {"param1"=>"value1", "param2"=>"value2", "param3"=>"value3"}
Hash[URI::decode_www_form(uri.query)] # if you are below 2.1 version of Ruby
# => {"param1"=>"value1", "param2"=>"value2", "param3"=>"value3"}
```

Read the method docomentation of [`::decode_www_form`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html#method-c-decode_www_form).

Answer (score 16):

Check out the [addressable](https://github.com/sporkmonger/addressable) gem - a popular replacement for Ruby's URI module that makes query parsing easy:

```
require "addressable/uri"
uri = Addressable::URI.parse("http://www.example.com/something?param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3")
uri.query_values['param1']
=> 'value1'
```

(It also apparently handles param encoding/decoding, unlike URI)

Comment: Sadly it looks this gem, like the `URI` library, has difficulty parsing query parameters in situations where the URL is weird. I.e. both fail to find query parameters when `url`s are odd, e.g. this: `http://localhost:4300/webapp/foo/#//controller/action?`  Leaving me to use a hack like:  `Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query(url.split("?").last)` to get the query parameters for parsing.

Answer (score 8):

Using CGI might be an outdated approach with Ruby 2.7/3.

Here's a neat way to do this with URI:

```rb
uri = URI.parse 'https://duckduckgo.com/?q=ruby+programming+language'
params = Hash[URI.decode_www_form uri.query]
# => {"q"=>"ruby programming language"}
```

Comment: Look, no additional libraries needed 

Answer (score 2):

you can also use this method

```rb
require 'uri'
require 'cgi'
uri = URI("https://example.com/?query=1&q=2&query=5")
a = CGI::parse(uri.query)
puts a                   #=> {"query"=>["1", "5"], "q"=>["2"]}
puts a["query"].to_s     #=> ["1", "5"]
puts a["query"][0]       #=>  1
puts a["query"][1]       #=>  5
puts a["q"][0]           #=>  2
```

its safe and much easier

Answer (score 2):

Sadly both the `URI` and `addressable` libraries break when attempting to extract query params from buggy URLs.  E.g. this breaks both:

```
http://localhost:4300/webapp/foo/#//controller/action?account=001-001-111&email=john%40email.com
```

Building on Arthur / Levi's solution, with `url.split("?").try(:last)` you can grab just the query param portion of the URL, and use `Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query` to parse that string of parameters into a hash.

Or in full:

```rb
Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query(url.split("?").try(:last))
```

returning in my example:

```
{"account": "001-001-111", "email": "john@email.com"}
```

Answer (score -4):

In your Controller, you should be able to access a dictionary (hash) called `params`. So, if you know what the names of each query parameter is, then just do `params[:param1]` to access it... If you don't know what the names of the parameters are, you could traverse the dictionary and get the keys.

Some simple examples [here](http://rails.learnhub.com/lesson/6371-action-controller-parameters).

Comment: OK, I knew that, it works well in the controller with the requested URL, but how to do that for others arbitrary URLs?