# How do I extract the value of the glid parameter from this URL in ruby?

Tags: ruby

http://share.findmespot.com/shared/faces/viewspots.jsp?glId=0rEE45o3ERRryMevW5teqS9gkNI

Comment: Check this answer, you can find multiple solutions there:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500462/how-to-extract-url-parameters-from-a-url-with-ruby-or-rails

Answer (score 0):

You can do using the string split method. Easiest way.

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :004 > a = 'http://share.findmespot.com/shared/faces/viewspots.jsp?glId=0rEE45o3ERRryMevW5teqS9gkNI'
 => "http://share.findmespot.com/shared/faces/viewspots.jsp?glId=0rEE45o3ERRryMevW5teqS9gkNI" 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :005 > b = a.split('=')[1]
 => "0rEE45o3ERRryMevW5teqS9gkNI"
```