# How do I parse a POST to my Rails 3.1 server manually?

Tags: https, ruby-on-rails-3.1, http-post, middleware

Scenario:
I have a Board model in my Rails server side, and an Android device is trying to post some content to a specific board via a POST. Finally, the server needs to send back a response to the Android device.

How do I parse the POST manually (or do I need to)? I am not sure how to handle this kind of external request. I looked into Metal, Middleware, HttpParty; but none of them seems to fit what I am trying to do. The reason I want to parse it manually is because some of the information I want will not be part of the parameters.

Does anyone know a way to approach this problem?

I am also thinking about using SSL later on, how might this affect the problem?

Thank you in advance!! :)

Comment: I found something useful: http://rails.nuvvo.com/lesson/6377-action-controller-the-request-and-response-objects

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to make a cross-domain request from ie9 to my rails app, and I needed to parse the body of a POST manually because ie9's XDR object restricts the contentType that we can send to `text/plain`, rather than `application/x-www-urlencoded` (see [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx)). Originally I had just been using the `params` hash provided by the controller, but once I restricted the contentType and dataType in my ajax request, that hash no longer contained the right information.

Following the URL in the comment above ([link](http://rails.nuvvo.com/lesson/6377-action-controller-the-request-and-response-objects)), I learned the how to recover that information. The author mentions that in a rails controller we always have access to a `request` variable that gives us an instance of the [ActionDispatch::Request object](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html). I tried to use `request.query_string` to get at the request body, but that just returned an empty string. A bit of snooping in the API, though, uncovered the [raw_post](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-raw_post) method. That method returned exactly what I needed!

To "parse it manually" you could iterate over the string returned by `request.raw_post` and do whatever you want, but I don't recommend it. I used Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query, as suggested in Arthur Gunn's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500462/how-to-extract-url-parameters-from-a-url-with-ruby-or-rails), to parse the raw_post into a hash. Once it is in hash form, you can shove whatever else you need in there, and then merge it with the params hash. Doing this meant I didn't have to change much else in my controller!

```
params.merge!(Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query(request.raw_post))
```

Hope that helps someone!

Answer (score -1):

Not sure exactly what you mean by "manually", posts are normally handled by the "create" or "update" methods in the controller. Check out the controller for your Board model, and you can add code to the appropriate method. You can access the params with the params hash.

You should be more specific about what you are trying to do. :)

Comment: The reason I want to parse it manually is because some of the information I want will not be part of the parameters.