# Replacing a %20 with a space in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, string

I've currently got a string that reads something like `["green%20books"]` and I'd like it to read `["green books"]`.

I thought Googling for this would yield a result pretty quickly but everyone just wants to turn spaces into `%20s`. Not the other way around.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Edit:

This is the function I'm working with and I'm confused where in here to decode the URL. I tried removing the URI.encode text but that broke the function.

```
def self.get_search_terms(search_url)
    hash = CGI.parse(URI.parse(URI.encode(search_url)).query) #returns a hash
    keywords = []
    hash.each do |key, value|
      if key == "q" || key == "p"
        keywords << value
      end
    end
    keywords
  end
```

Comment: Are you using Rails?  If so, does `params[:q]` not meet your needs?

Comment: Yes, I am using Rails. I'm not sure that my string is a param of anything...

Comment: I can understand wanting a utility method here.  However, the parameter parsing itself probably shouldn't be something the controller -- or a helper -- concerns itself with.  Maybe define the method in terms of a `Hash` (e.g., `params` within a controller) instead.

Comment: This is being done inside of a model, for what that's worth...

Comment: In that case, this might be a duplicate of [How to extract URL parameters from a URL with Ruby or Rails?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500462/how-to-extract-url-parameters-from-a-url-with-ruby-or-rails).  Does that question help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use regular expressions:

```
string = "green%20books"
string.gsub!('%20', ' ')

puts string
```

Comment: In fact, there's no need for regex: string.gsub!('%20', ' ')

Comment: @pguardiario Though note that internally `gsub` converts the string to a regex anyway.

Comment: Following `gsub` into the C source: `str_gsub` → `get_pat` → `rb_reg_regcomp` → `rb_reg_new_str` → `rb_reg_init_str` → `rb_reg_alloc` → `rb_reg_s_alloc`, which returns a new Regexp.

Comment: @pguardiario: A string argument will be regex-ified but it will be escaped first (using `rb_reg_quote`) so you don't have to worry about `gsub('.*')` treating `.*` as a regex rather than a plain string.

Comment: @Andrew - that's interesting, do you have a link to where we can see that? What about rubinius/jruby?

Comment: @pguardiario Download the C source, I don't have the energy at the moment to go back and retrace the path while providing GitHub srouce links (though I wish I did `:\`). With some use of Ack it's not too hard to track things down, and the call path is exactly what I said it was above.

Answer (score 20):

you can use the 'unencode' method of URI. (aliased as decode)

```
require 'uri'
URI.decode("green%20books")
# => "green books"
```

this will not only replaces "%20" with space, but every uri-encoded charcter, which I assume is what you want.

[documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI/Escape.html#method-i-unescape)

Comment: `URI.decode` and `URI.encode` have been deprecated for years. See @benjamin-oakes answer.

Answer (score 5):

[`CGI::unescape`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI.html#method-c-unescape) will do what you want:

```
1.9.2-p320 :001 > require 'cgi'
=> true 
1.9.2-p320 :002 > s = "green%20books"
=> "green%20books" 
1.9.2-p320 :003 > CGI.unescape(s)
=> "green books"
```

Another option (as YenTheFirst mentioned) might be `URI.decode`.  However, [I read a discussion that it would be deprecated](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/207489) -- although that was in 2010.

Anyway, since you're asking about arrays, you would perhaps `map` using that method:

```
ary.map { |s| CGI.unescape(s) }
```