# Match regex works for one search, but scan does not

Tags: ruby, regex

The following gets me one match:

```
query = http://0.0.0.0:9393/review?first_name=aoeu&last_name=rar
find = /(?<=(\?|\&)).*?(?=(\&|\z))/.match(query)
```

When I examine 'find' I get:

```
first_name=aoeu
```

I want to match everything between a '?' and a '&', so I tried

```
find = query.scan(/(?<=(\?|\&)).*?(?=(\&|\z))/)
```

But yet when I examine 'find' I now get:

```
[["?", "&"], ["&", ""]]
```

What do I need to do to get:

```
[first_name=aoeu][last_name=rar]
```

or

```
["first_name=aoeu","last_name=rar"]
```

?

Comment: i think `Ruby` does not support lookbehind `(?<=(\?|\&))`

Comment: i tested your expression in `.net` flavor and it works fine.

Comment: @sawa Really? but it failed when I tested it on my `RegexBuddy 3.5.4`.

Comment: @JohnWoo What version of Ruby do you use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `String#split`.

```
query.split(/[&?]/).drop(1)
```

or

```
query[/(?<=\?).*/].split("&")
```

But if your real purpose is to extract the parameters from url, then [question and its answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500462).

Comment: thank you! fwiw to anyone else tripped by this, query.split(/[&?]/).drop(1) results in the second scenario I asked for.

Comment: @shicholas I realized that, and changed my answer, but the original one with your modification may be better.

Answer (score 3):

Use other module provided by ruby or rails will make your code more maintainable and readable.

```
require 'uri'
uri = 'http://0.0.0.0:9393/review?first_name=aoeu&last_name=rar'

require 'rack'
require 'rack/utils'
Rack::Utils.parse_query(URI.parse(uri).query)
# => {"first_name"=>"aoeu", "last_name"=>"rar"}

# or CGI
require 'cgi'
CGI::parse(URI.parse(uri).query)
# => {"first_name"=>["aoeu"], "last_name"=>["rar"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need extract query params from URI, please, check thread ["How to extract URL parameters from a URL with Ruby or Rails?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500462/how-to-extract-url-parameters-from-a-url-with-ruby-or-rails). It contains a lot of solutions without using regexps.