# In Rails, how can I take a GET string and parse it into an object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I’m positive this is a dupe, but I couldn’t find the original.

Given a GET-style string like `foo=bar&x[0]=baz`, how can I decode this into a `params`-like array in a Rails app?

---

**Updated to add**: Note that `CGI.parse` seems to do much less than whatever magic Rails does:

```
1.9.3p194 :006 > CGI::parse 'foo=bar&x[foo][bar]=baz'
 => {"foo"=>["bar"], "x[foo][bar]"=>["baz"]}
```

CGI.parse didn’t unpack the nested objects into a mult-level hash. In Rails, at some level, this is actually examined.

Comment: Here's one with several possible answers: [How to extract URL parameters...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500462/how-to-extract-url-parameters-from-a-url-with-ruby-or-rails)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For nested queries, Rails uses Racks' parameter parser `Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query`:

```
Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query 'foo=bar&x[foo][bar]=baz'
 => {"foo"=>"bar", "x"=>{"foo"=>{"bar"=>"baz"}}}
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems Rails does more magic on top of this, though, especially w.r.t. hard brackets. Editing my question to add this.