# Remove specific parts from url

Tags: ruby

Lets suppose I have a url like this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch/3e4345?v=rwmEkvPBG1s

What is the best and shorthest way to only get the `3e4345` part?
Sometimes it doesn't contain additional params in `?` 
I don't want to use any gems.

What I did was:

```
    url =  url.split('/watch/')
    url =  url[1].split('/')[0].split('?')[0]
```

Is there a better way? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

possibly the safest and best one. use URI.

```
URI("https://www.youtube.com/watch/34345?v=rwmEkvPBG1s").path.split("/").last
```

For more refer [How to extract URL parameters from a URL with Ruby or Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500462/how-to-extract-url-parameters-from-a-url-with-ruby-or-rails)

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following and using the match function to find a match based on a regular expression statement. The value at [1] is the first capture from the regular expression. I have included a breakdown from regexper.com to help illustrate what the expression is accomplishing.

You will notice parentheses around the \d+ which are what captures the digits out of the URL when it matches.

```
url.to_s.match(/\/watch\/(\d+).*$/)[1]
```

[image: Regexper]

Comment: Perfect but the code can be also a string. But the code ends with `/` or `?` or with nothing for sure. So it could be:   `wer34/hello` or `wer34/` or `wer34?locale=3` or `wer34`. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
x = "https://www.youtube.com/watch/34345?v=rwmEkvPBG1s"
File.basename(URI(x).path)
=> "34345"
```